# Как сделать ЧПУ в .htaccess, с site.ru/katalog/99 на site.ru/moenazvanie

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Доброго дня. У меня весьма смутное понимание ЧПУ и редиректов, попытки что то сделать и гугления не дают пока результатов.
Задача: есть страница на сайте с ардесом http://site.ru/katalog-otzyvov/99/
Необходимо что бы эта страница была доступна по адресу http://site.ru/fasadnye-raboty

Answer (score 2):

Используя mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?category=$1&id=$2
```

Подробнее в гугл по запросу mod_rewrite

Comment: Если я более менее правильно разобрался то то что идет после [a-zA-Z] будет подставлено в category а то что в [0-9] в $2.
Может вы не внимательно прочитали, мне надо превратить конкретно адрес http://site.ru/katalog-otzyvov/99/ в адрес вида http://site.ru/fasadnye-raboty. Речи о каких та index.php или category вообще не идет. Да я гуглил эту тему, но хоть убей не получается (((

Answer (score 1):

Если вы перенаправляете все на index.php, где в ручную парсите УРИ, то довольно просто.
Заводите в БД колонки `URL` и `OLD_URL`, которые заполняете соответственно новыми и старыми адресами. Затем отправляете запрос в БД "`SELECT * WHERE URL='$url'`", если ничего не возвращает, пробуете "`SELECT * WHERE OLD_URL='$url'`", если вернет строку, то делаете перманентный (301-й) редирект на содержимое колонки URL. Если опять ничего -> выдаем 404. Плюсы такого подхода, что ваши страницы не выпадут из индекса, и постепенно поисковики заменят их новыми.

в .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```